# Display inner div above outer div

Tags: html, css

Inside a inner div I have some content, that I want to display over and outside the outer div.

I'm looking for a css class to display the content above all other content.
I thought to fix it with css overflow, but I can get it fixed.

It is because of the padding left and right. And should be displayed over the padding-left of the div with class "item".

What class do I need to use?

CODE:

```
<div class="item product col-sm-3 product-display-standard item-animated" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px">
    <div class="tooltip fade top in">
        <div class="tooltip-inner">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your html/css code?

Comment: Please post your html/css code and image of expected output as well.

Comment: @ashkufaraz Edit the question.

Comment: `<div class="class=" tooltip-inner ">TEXT</div>` it is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

[CSS z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the position to `relative` of the inner div and then changing the `top` property to be -(val)px.
HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.inner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw4a8vg9/).